# Mint 16 using remote desktop on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux-mint, vnc-viewer

Im using desktop sharing on mint 16 and connecting on windows 7 with vnc4 viewer and it works 100% but when I switch on the Uncomplicated Firewall on mint 16 it blocks me from using desktop sharing. Please tell me how to get UFW to allow VNC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your question: are you connecting from Windows to a VNC server running on Mint? If so, the command you need is:

```
  sudo ufw allow 5901/tcp
```

on Mint. This assumes that the port you are using is 5901. If the above command does not work, it means you are using a different port. To identify the port, issue the command:

```
  sudo ss -lntp | grep vnc
```

You will get an output like:

```
  LISTEN     0      5                         *:5903                     *:*      users:(("Xtightvnc",17136,3))
```

from which you see that the listening port if 5903. Modify the ufw command accordingly.

Comment: you understanding correctly. The last command you gave me has absolutely no response to see what my tcp is. if my ufw is disabled my remote desktop works as soon as I enable it, vnc stops working.

Comment: @user325114 Are you sure your vnc server (on Mint) is running?

Comment: yes im on it now. but if i enable the firewall i cant connect

Comment: @Albert On Mint, what is the output of *sudo ss -lntp | grep vnc*?

Comment: It was 5900. Thank you very much for all your help.